# Minimum Distance Between Two Parallel Planes Given Points in Space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

I'm given a number of points (in this case 7) and need to calculate the minimum distance between two parallel planes which "sandwich" or encompass all of the given points.  The goal is to calculate flatness of the specimen.

I'm not even sure how to approach this...

[Surface flatness example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuB3l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute the Hessian Normalform of the plane,given by $$\frac{ax+by+cz+d}{\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=0$$

Comment: Thank you.  This is an occupational / work task...not a student / learning thing.

Comment: I'm thinking that I may be looking to use the minimum zone method to perform this calculation....

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking the width of the convex hull of your point set.
Compute the convex hull $H$. Then the width is determined either
by a vertex and a face of $H$ (i.e., one plane determined by a face, the other antipodal and parallel, touching at a vertex), or by two skew edges. Since you only have $n=7$ points, you can just check all {point,face} and {edge,edge} pairs: $O(n^2)$ complexity.

*Added* to illustrate the need for edge-edge width support.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Am I wrong to think you find the 35 planes through each possible triple of points and find the one that minimize the furthest-away remaining point?

Comment: @stevengregory - how can I be sure that the planes used for the minimum distance calculate are parallel?

Comment: @scootsch The first plane has to contain three of the seven points. The second plane can contain one to all of the remaining points. It just has to be parallel to the first.

Comment: @stevengregory: You must also check edge-edge support of parallel planes. Two non-parallel edges could realize the width. For example, form a tetrahedron as the hull of two edges, one at $z=0$ along $x$-axis, and one at $z=1$ along $y$-axis.

Comment: @scootsch: Added figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using a linear programming approach

Given the points $p_k$ and a vector $\vec n = (a,b,c)$ we need to solve the linear problem

$$
\min_{a,b,c,d} d\ \ \text{s. t. }\ \ -d \le p_k\cdot \vec n \le d,\ \ \text{for}\ \ k=1,2,\cdots,n
$$